# Slope along a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, proportional-editing

I have a long path object that I designed in top-down view, but I want to have a downward slope over the whole thing.

Is there a quick way I could do this? Like position my first and last points where I want them on the Z axis and interpolate all other points along the curve?

Answer (score 2):

To change the slope of your curve, without changing the projected view in top view, you can use the *Proportional Editing* tool with a *Linear* falloff in *Projected* mode. You can find it in the top middle of the viewport. Use these settings:

[image: Proportional editing settings]

Select the vertex or vertices on the far end of the curve that should be at the bottom of the slope:

[image: Curve]

Go to the side view, hit <kbd>G</kbd> to move, <kbd>Z</kbd> to restrict the move along the Z-axis, and use the scroll wheel to adjust the area that is affected by the proportional editing tool. It is a grey circle around the pivot point. Try to get the circle as close to the highest part of the slope as possible without having those vertices inside the circle:

[image: Slope]

Place the slope however you like and hit enter to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly made a bezier closed curve:
[image]

And Hendriks3D's solution unfortunately doesn't produce a perfect slope,

[image]

At least if the perfect slope would produce a straight line when viewed from the side... For this kind of effect you want to shrinkwrap on an actual slope plane:

[image]

Probably not what you need, but if you want the traveler who travels with a constant speed along the curve, to also lower with a constant rate (both $\vec{V}$ and its Z component are constant), then you'd use a Geometry Nodes setup like this:

[image]

(left the plane for reference)